# Power query: why doesn't the Standard in add column work?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, business-intelligence

Why doesn't the Standard in add column work?

[image: why the Standard in add column doesn't work ?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The add standard column will "perform basic math operations".  You have selected a text column ("ABC").  If it is a numeric column then convert it first.